# How to test kernel sleep method in module in Rspec 3.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, kernel

I have the following method in the private section of a module...

```
  def add_api_delay
    sleep(retry_delay * (retry_multiplier_adjustment - retries)) if retries.positive?
  end
```

The spec I am working with looks like this so far...

```
  let!(:klass) do
    Class.new do
      include AmazonMws::Shared::Utilities
      attr_accessor :retries, :retry_multiplier_adjustment, :retry_delay
      def initialize
        @retries = 1
        @retry_delay = 1
        @retry_multiplier_adjustment = 2
      end

      def test_add_api_delay
        add_api_delay
      end
    end
  end

  describe '.add_api_delay', focus: true do
    # let(:kernel_spy) { class_spy(Kernel, sleep: true) }

    before do

    end

    it 'sleeps retry api calls' do
      # allow(klass).to receive(:sleep).with(1).and_return(kernel_spy)
      # expect(kernel_spy).to have_received(:sleep)
      # expect(Kernel).to receive(:sleep).with(1)
      expect(Kernel).to receive(:sleep).and_return(true)
      klass.new.test_add_api_delay
    end
  end
```

I have a few goals and reasons I want to test this private method, but how do verify sleep has been called.  I do not want to slow down the suite so ideally I am trying to use a class spy against Kernel.  Nothing I am testing seems to work.

**UPDATE**

```
  describe '.add_api_delay' do
    before do
      allow_any_instance_of(klass).to receive(:sleep).and_return(1)
    end

    it 'sleeps retry api calls' do
      expect(klass.new.test_add_api_delay).to eq(1)
    end
  end
```

This works, however, it is not ideal as it flags the following cop...

```
C: RSpec/AnyInstance: Avoid stubbing using allow_any_instance_of
      allow_any_instance_of(klass).to receive(:sleep).and_return(1)
```

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it's not working because you're not putting the expectation on the right thing. It looks like you've tried putting it on `Kernel`, and on the class under test, but you need to put it on the instance:

```
it 'sleeps retry api calls' do
  thing = klass.new
  allow(thing).to receive(:sleep)

  thing.test_add_api_delay

  expect(thing).to have_received(:sleep).with(1)
end
```

The above has a test smell in that it is stubbing the class under test. But I think it's probably better than enforcing some design constraint here and losing some of Ruby's elegance in just calling `sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use allow_any_instace_of

```
RSpec.describe "allow_any_instance_of" do
  it "returns the specified value on any instance of the class" do
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:foo).and_return(:return_value)

    o = Object.new
    expect(o.foo).to eq(:return_value)
  end
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about that but that fails the cops from https://github.com/backus/rubocop-rspec

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of an RSpec test of a private method that calls sleep.

```
class Sleeper
  def initialize(delay:)
    @delay = delay
  end
  attr_reader :delay

  private

  def rest
    sleep delay
  end
end

require 'rspec'

RSpec.describe Sleeper do
  let(:sleeper) { Sleeper.new(delay: delay) }
  let(:delay) { 10 }

  # Comment here explaining why this test is necessary
  describe '.send :rest' do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(Sleeper).to receive(:sleep) }

     it 'sleeps' do
       expect(sleeper).to receive(:sleep)
       sleeper.send :rest
     end
  end
end
```

UPDATE:

You have to make a decision here.

Rubocop's advice to "Avoid stubbing" is good advice but you said you had reasons for testing whether a private method uses a kernal method, and stubbing is the best way to do that. If those reasons for testing are more important that Rubocop purity, you should ignore the Rubocop warning.

If Rubocop's advice is more important, then I suggest writing a public method that computes the delay, write tests for that. Maybe something like:

```
def retry_delay_duration
  return 0 if retries < 1
  retry_delay * (retry_multiplier_adjustment - retries)
end

private

def add_api_delay
  sleep retry_delay_duration
end
```

In this second case, you should delete the tests for `add_api_delay` and only test the public method `retry_delay_duration` (or whatever you call it) returns the correct delay.

Comment: thoughts added, as this suggestion is not working. have any other ideas?

Comment: but if a developer just comments out or replaces sleep will it be covered?  also, it is my understanding that using "allow_any_instance_of" is poor practice.

Comment: You have to recognize and own your intentions. Testing this way is "implementation" testing, and it's not a poor practice if there's business case for doing it. It's true, Ruby isn't a great language for making this kind of constraint, but we all have to make do with what we have. In this example, the object has power to halt the runtime for an arbitrary length of time (your real code, I'm sure, sets some kind of max duration). If you _have_ to do that, doing some kind of implementation test around it seems wise. It's brittle, but you'll refactor it away when you start using a job queue.

Comment: Clarification and correction: by "wise" I mean "better than nothing." By "brittle" I mean, "brittle and not nearly as helpful as one might hope, but better than nothing." And by "runtime" I mean "current thread".

Comment: This spec was for use in a job queue scenario. The goal was to make sure sleep was used and the settings were received.  If I tested the method outside of it the sleep command could be removed.